# Django projects fail on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: django

I just upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, and **ALL** my Django projects (tens of them) were not working.

1. One of the problem related to psycopg2 when executing pip:

For example, there is "psycopg2==2.7.3.1" in my "requirements.txt" file, and running "pip install -r requirements.txt" resulted in errors when building wheel for psycopg2.
Change "psycopg2==2.7.3.1" to ""psycopg2-binary" solved the problem.

So, is such change necessary for all projects running on Ubuntu 20.04?

2. Other error examples from various projects when running server:

   RuntimeError: `__class__` not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser'>. Was `__classcell__` propagated to type.`__new__`?

   SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized (widgets.py, line 151)

   AssertionError: SRE module mismatch

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decimal'

... etc.

How to I fix these problems? I've been in a headache for weeks.

Comment: The way to address this is *one problem at a time*.  Research each problem, searching for a solution ... then asking a specific question about >>just<< that problem, giving all of the relevant code and error messages for >>just<< that problem.  Asking for a fix for all of your problems is like asking for a solution to the problem of War.

Comment: Yes, I know: one problem at a time. But these problems relates to Ubuntu 20.04 as a whole; otherwise, I would have to ask tens of problems.

Comment: These are not problems with Ubuntu 20.04 "as a whole".  These are problems with the specific versions of the various 3rd-party dependencies that your Django projects are using ... and *their* compatibility with the "focal" environment.  Just normal python stuff ... and there is no magic solution to deal with this kind of thing.

Comment: *"... otherwise, I would have to ask tens of problems."* - I assume that 8 out of 10 you would be able to solve without asking a question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with psycopg2 is apparently due to an incompatibility between python 3.8 and older versions of psycopg2.  ([Issue #854](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/854))

The problem has been fixed, but it was not backported to the release that you are using.  It has however been backported to the binary psycopg2 releases in various Linux distros.

So ... yes ... you are going to have to make some changes for all of your Django projects that use psycopg2 to get them to run on vanilla Ubuntu 20.04.

However, it looks like there are at least 3 ways to "fix" this:

- Change to the "binary" package as you have done.
- Change the psycopg2 version in your "requirements.txt" to 2.8.6 or later<sup>1</sup>.
- Build, install and use python 3.7 or earlier.  (Probably a bad idea in this case.)

---

<sup>1 - Or maybe 2.8.0_BETA2 or later because it looks like the fix has been backported that far in the source code repo.  It depends on whether the patched releases were uploaded to PyPi ... which I didn't check.  But all things being equal, updating to the most recent compatible version is preferable.</sup>